# Como exibir erros do PHP usando Ajax e JSON?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Sabe aquelas mensagens de erro que o PHP retorna quando escrevemos algum código errado ou, por exemplo, chamamos alguma variável que não existe, ou ainda tentamos dar include num arquivo inexistente.
Quando fazemos uma requisição Ajax sem usar o JSON e pedimos pra ele imprimir o retorno no console, a mensagem de erro é exibida. Mas quando estamos usando datatype JSON, não. Só retorna o que mandamos retornar (isso se não houver nenhum erro no código).
Como fazer então para que as mensagem de erro do PHP sejam exibidas quando estamos usando Ajax e JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Bom, normalmente eu faço o seguinte;

```
$message = array("message" => "", "error" => "");
try{
    //Seu código aqui
}catch (Exception $e){
    $message['message'] = "Coloque a mensagem de erro aqui";
    $message['error'] = $e->getMessage();
    return $message;
}
```

Neste caso, imaginemos que esse pedaço de código é um return de uma função. Ao receber o valor você da um:

> json_encode($retorno); exit();

No retorno da função ajax eu fiz um metodo geral que identifica se ele retornou esse json com o error != "", demonstrando que ele retornou o erro. Faço a verificação e envio o message->error para o console.log(); ou dependendo do local jogo isso para um alerta bonitinho na tela; Não retornando isso ele simplesmente mantem o que ele iria fazer normalmente.

```
$.ajax({
      url : "cadastrar.php",
      type : 'post',
      dataType: "json",
      data : {
           nome : "Maria Fernanda",
           salario :'3500'
      }
 })
 .success(function(data){ //data = retorno json do php
      if(hasError(data)){
        messagemDeErroQualquer(data);
      }else{
        facaOQueDeveriaFazer();
      }
 }) 

function hasError(data){
    if (typeof data.error !== 'undefined') {
        return true;
    }else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Testei aqui e não deu certo

Comment: Assim, você faz a chamada ajax, espera o retorno ou erro do mesmo à chamada. Não esqueça de colocar o "dataType" como json, se não ele irá interpretar como somente um text/html qualquer. Se ocorrer de retornar um erro, a sua função dentro do php (dentro do try/catch) irá fazer com que force o retorno de um array com o "message" e "error". Como não houve "erros" no arquivo php, pois não retornou um exception sem tratamento, ele irá entrar normalmente na função "success" do ajax. Ali verifique se existe ou não a variavel "error" dentro de "data". Se tiver, deu pau. Se não, continue seu trabalho.